# Is glottal stop before last syllable becoming much more common? (NA English)

Tags: pronunciation

What is the more accepted and common pronunciation in the US?

(< = glottal stop)

Word: Accurate

Pronunciation: "<Ack your rut", or "<Ack your <ut"

Word: "Higgens" (last name)

Pronunciation: "Hig gens", or "Higg <ens" / "Higg <ins"

Word: "Horten" (last name)

Pronunciation: "Hort ten" / "Hor tin", or "Hort <en" / "Hort <in"

Word: Mountain

"Moun ton" / "Mount ten" / "Moun tin", or "Mount <en / "Mount <in"

Word: Historical

Pronounciation:

"His tor rick cul", or "His tor ric <ul", or "His tor <ic <ul"<sup>1</sup>

So basically this is a question about inserting a glottal stop before the last syllable of certain words.  Has this practice recently (last few years, or 1-2 decades?) become much more widespread?

In the case of two-syllable words, the practice is often (but not always) accompanied by an unusual (to my ears) lengthening of the pause between the the syllables, and often by a "clipping" or shortening of the first syllable, and sometimes even a slight elevation of the pitch of the first syllable.  The whole effect is to make the word seem somehow "cuter" (cute <er?) and diminutive, seemingly well suited to words like "kitten" (kit <in) and the like.  One therefore might wonder whether there is any statistical correlation towards increased usage when describing objects/ animals that most people would agree are diminutive or "cute" -- as well as any gender or age bias of any kind as to the employment of this practice, either on the part of the gender of the speaker and/or, in the case of a name, the gender or age of the person being named.

In some words (e.g. "kitten") the last syllable seems to be shifted toward more of an "in" sound, too.

But anyway the actual question is just about practice of putting a glottal stop at the front of the last syllable of certain words, and whether this is becoming much more common.

I was surprised to hear this practice so frequently in a recent radio program featuring young native Spanish speakers in the US, speaking English.  Perhaps is was just a coincidence-- there doesn't seem to be anything about the Spanish language that tends to lend itself to this practice -- (I doubt that anyone is saying "Bur rit <oh" or "Bur <eat <oh" for "Burrito"... )

Footnotes:

1. Ok, being slightly facetious here (or should I say fuss <esh <us?) in also adding the glottal stop to the second-to-last syllable.  Wouldn't be too surprised to start hearing that soon though.  The practice I'm describing seems to be mostly confined to two-syllable words at present, and in longer words, usually only the last syllable is involved.

Related questions:

[Accented syllable after a glottal stop in NA English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/444955/accented-syllable-after-a-glottal-stop-in-na-english)

Comment: [ɑjmˈʃəɹ julˈhe?͡θɪs bəɾɑj ˈɑnəslijəv ˌnowɑjˈdijə hwət͡ʃuˈmin bɑj ðoz pɹəˈnənsijˌeʃənz. kʊd͡ʒə ˈpliz ˈedət͡ʃəɹ ˈpostən kənˈvəɹt ðəm tə juz ðə ˈstændəɹ ˌdɪnəɹˈnæʃənəɫ fəˈnəɾək ˈælfəbət soðæˈtɑjən ˌmosˈtəðəɹ ˈməmbəɹ zəvɑwɹ kəˈmjunɪɾi kənəv ˌəni ˈt͡ʃænsəˌtəndɹˈstændɪŋ hwət͡ʃuv ˈmənthiɹ. ˌθeŋgzəˈlɑ?](https://ipa.typeit.org/full/)

Comment: I wonder whether this isn't [the so-called "hard attack"](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22hard+attack%22) that some kids are doing these days.

Comment: There was a now-closed question about button vs but-in that might have some relevance, but for some reason I can't seem to search it up --

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever heard this general 'glottal stop insertion', but there is certainly a change in New England English of word final '...ton' (/...tən/ or ...tn/) to /...?ən/ eg 'button' -> /'bʌ ?ən/.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/602493/2085).

Comment: @tchrist - that's it.

Comment: Just heard another one (on radio interview), "Certain" pronounce as "Surt <in" rather that "Sur ton" or "Surt "tin".  Speaker a middle-age man, a college professor teaching English esp creative writing.  Now, just wondering, do the choir directors going along with this trend these days?  Thinking of the Christmas carol "The First Noel" with line that goes "Was to certain ("surt in"?) poor shepherds in fields as they lay"...

Comment: There's a famous music video that went viral by a 13-year old girl, just featured on NPR "Hidden Brain" (not for any reason relating to our topic), the line sounds something like "Fry Day, Fry Day, Get In Down on Fry Day." ("getting down on Friday") . Oh yeah then we have "Made In Cookware" being mentioned as a sponsor in NPR. That's the name spelled correctly. But considering the way things are going, I had to google the name to make sure that what I was hearing didn't actually represent "Maiden Cookware", because that too would probably get the identical pronunciation as "Made In".

Comment: There's something else going on here that my question hasn't fully conveyed.  In the "older"/standard pronunciation of "butter" or "button" or "mountain", the last consonant dividing the syllables (the t) is often arguably entirely absent from the end of the first syllable, while unmistakably present at the start of the second syllable.   In the "new" pronunciation, where the second syllable starts with a glottal stop, the final dividing constant (the t in the examples above) is moved to the end of the first syllable, though not aspirated.  Question could probably be improved to convey this--

Comment: @tchrist --see final comment above-- does that make sense?  I think I should probably rework question to convey more clearly--  a lot of overlap but I don't think it's quite a complete duplicate of question linked at end of question text--

Comment: @quietflyer I still can't tell whether you're talking about [*t*-glottalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-glottalization) or about [ejective consonants](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rP0-MfE4zbA) where we stop the glottis after a still-pronounced stop before we start a vowel following.